# SQL Query but Eliminate Some Records based on another Query

Tags: sql

I can loop through the table produced by the following query

```
Select userid_fk as id, courseID_fk 
from tbl_userCourse 
inner join tbl_users 
        on user_id=userid_fk 
where courseID_fk=5
```

and then get rid of some records where the following sql results in empty (I have to pass in the $user_id).  I can do this on a web page using php using this query.

```
Select min(schDate) as min 
from tbl_schedule 
where userid_fk=".$user_id." 
  and schDate>getDate()  
  and courseID_fk=5
```

But now I'm wondering if I can combine these two sql statement somehow and just use one query statement.  If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Please re-read your question. The phrase "where the following sql results in empty" is confusing to me

Comment: that means the sql results in 0 rows as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Exists

```
Select userid_fk as id, courseID_fk 
from tbl_userCourse 
inner join tbl_users 
        on user_id=userid_fk 
where courseID_fk=5
and exists (
    Select * 
    from tbl_schedule 
    where tbl_schedule.userid_fk = tbl_userCourse.userid_fk
      and tbl_schedule.schDate>getDate()  
      and tbl_schedule.courseID_fk=5
)
```

`Exists` returns true if the query between braces has at least one record, so `and exits (...)` will "skip" those in which that subquery is empty.

As you see this query is quite readable as it resembles what you explained you want

Comment: Thanks, well that returns all the rows, not sure why.

Comment: I do have an id in that table called schID

Comment: I'm running this in SSMS and it throws an error Invalid column name 'id'.

Comment: Please have a look, I'm using whole table name in now subquery... does it work now?

Comment: Yeah....this should work but I'm still getting all rows..I'm wondering if Exists is true if no rows are returned...that seems strange.

Comment: actually, I see the output is null from the subquery...I'll see if I can put this into sqlfiddle and I'll let you know...thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, sure, min will always return a record, I changed select min... to select *, now finally it should work...

Comment: Thanks...that did it

Answer (score 0):

You should use a join

```
Select tbl_userCourse.userid_fk as id, tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk , min(schDate)
from tbl_userCourse 
inner join tbl_users on tbl_users.user_id=userid_fk 
inner join tbl_schedule  on tbl_schedule.user_id =  tbl_users.user_id
where tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk=5
and tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk=tbl_schedule.courseID_fk
and schDate>getDate()
```

or if group by is required then

```
Select userid_fk as id, courseID_fk , min(schDate)
from tbl_userCourse 
inner join tbl_users on tbl_users.user_id=userid_fk 
inner join tbl_schedule  on tbl_schedule.user_id =  tbl_users.user_id
where tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk=5
and tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk=tbl_schedule.courseID_fk
and schDate>getDate()
group by tbl_userCourse.userid_fk , tbl_userCourse.courseID_fk
```